# Why I can not see bugs from Findbugs on SonarQube?

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube, findbugs

I have installed Findbugs-Plug-in in Sonarqube and activate it (set as default). I have my maven-project in eclipse. If I run this project, I become 47 bugs and can see all in Bug Explorer. In Run Configuration I have as goal findbugs:findbugs sonar:sonar; as Parameter Name / Value: Dsonar.projectKey/ wawi-db-layer, Dsonar.host.url/ http://localhost:9000, Dsonar.login/ token number, Dsonar.java.findbugs.reportPaths/ /target/findbugsXml.xml. After Run Configuration is my build successfull. But I can not see these 47 bugs in SonarQube. If I use Sonar way I can see 13 bugs. Why these additionally 47 bugs from Findbugs are not shown in SonarQube?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I doubt that the parameter names are supposed to all start with "D". Is that a carryover from a command line where you had to run with something like -Dsonar.login=nnnnn?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roGVx.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1uEE.png)

I make it in Eclipse under Run Configuration. With "D" it works good. I have results on SonarQube. But these reselts are not from FindBugs, they are from SonarWay